# Proving that a hypersurface has codimension 1

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I need a hint or a solution in a question I'm struggling:

> Let $Y$ be an affine variety of dimension $r$ in $\mathbb{A}^n$. Let $H$ be a
>   hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}^n$, and assume that $Y \nsubseteq H$. Then every
>   irreducible component of $Y \cap H$ has dimension $r - 1$.

I don't know even how to begin, any help is really welcome

Comment: Hi, where did you find the question?

Comment: @B11b Hartshorne algebraic geometry page 8 exercise 1.8

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use [Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the great [*Gathmann's AG notes*](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/main.pdf), *Proposition 4.2.4*. page 55.

Comment: Thank you, I'm reading it right now